# Is there any browser plugin or js library that allows rotate 3D DWG objects?

Tags: browser, 3d, cad, dwg, autocad-plugin

Have you seen somthing like this? 
I tryed http://www.autodwg.com/dwg-viewer/dwgviewx.htm, but it seems it supports just 2D objects

Another problem is taht it should work under IE8.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called Three JS, you can find it here http://threejs.org/

But basically you need to convert the file to a obj extension.